# Model creates blank page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when I enter information into my form for a new page, it lets you select which author has created the page, this all works fine.
when I go to save the page i get this error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PagesController#create

Author(#2162588860) expected, got String(#2151988680)
```

it also says I have problems in my Pages_controller in the create action and the show action.

```
def create
@page = Page.new(params[:page])

  if @page.save
      redirect_to(@page, :notice => 'Page was successfully created.')
  else
      render :action => "new"
  end
end 

  def show
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

end

I have changed the params :id to author and it saves an empty record with none of the content that was entered in the form. What should I put in the params? or in the create and show action .

thank you

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you `have changed the params :id to author`? Describe your associations here as the error clearly tells that your associations don't match.

Comment: I have tried changing to .to_i on all of the @page and in the params[:id]. when I change the params[:page] to params[:author] it returns the create template but all the fields are empty?? so it returns an empty form? this has me stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks, like you try to set author param to string while you need to set author_id. I can suupose, you used select control in form, builded like this:

```
f.select(:author, ... )
```

instead of

```
f.select(:author_id, ... )
```